# writing a changing variable to csv file to different rows

Tags: python, csv

i am writing a script that loop through a api query and generate a variable value. In every loop, this variable value is different.

can someone help me how can i save each values to a csv file in different rows.

current, it just overwrite the value instead of saving old value.

```
import csv

data_value=xml['call1']['status']
with open ('bitrate.csv','w') as csvfile:
     fieldnames=['number','data']
     thewriter= csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=fieldnames)
     thewriter.writeheader()
     thewriter.writerow({'number':row_count, 'data':data_value})
     row_count +=1
```

Comment: I guess you need to open the file in append mode after the first time.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file with `open(filename, 'w')`, you are in *write* mode, so you will overwrite the current file contents.  To append to the existing file contents, use `open(filename, 'a')`.  Or, even better, to append to the existing file contents if the file exists, and create a new file if it doesn't exist, use `open(filename, 'a+')`.

Finally, `csv` files should be opened with the extra keyword argument `newline=''` (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3)

So you should have:

```py
open('bitrate.csv', 'a+', newline='')
```

Comment: How would you know you'd created a new file? You need to decide whether to write the headers.